# LSTM forecasting horizontal line with standardized datas

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm

I’ve seen many topics about the problem I have in my situation but nothing help.
I am trying to make a forecast on a stock price with a Bidirectional LSTM.
My problem here is that the forecast on test datas looks like almost horizontal during the whole period.
My data are standardized, and I tried to increase the number of epochs (actual is 300, but I tried 2000 and i got only nan values in prediction which seems to be caused by Exploding gradents).
Can you explain me if I made something wrong in my code ? I’ve been working on this since a week and cannot understand where am I wrong.

Thanks you a lot !!!

My code and final output :

```
!pip install yfinance

For reading stock data from yahoo
from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader
import yfinance as yf

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

For time stamps
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
end = datetime.now()
print (‘end’,end)

start = “1900-01-01”
print(start)
print (‘start’,start)
globals()[‘SGO’] = yf.download(‘SGO.PA’, start, end,progress=False)
globals()[‘SGO’]=globals()[‘SGO’].filter([‘Close’])
symbols=‘SGO’
dic_train_len={}
data_array={}
data_array[symbols] = globals()[symbols].values
dic_train_len[symbols] = int(np.ceil( len(data_array[symbols]) * .90))
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

Créer un dictionnaire pour stocker les scalers
dictio_scalers = {}

Fonction pour scaler un ensemble de données et conserver l’objet scaler
def scale_data(nom_symbole, dataset):
 scaler = StandardScaler()
 scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
 dictio_scalers[nom_symbole] = scaler
 return scaled_data

dictio_scaled_values = {}
dataset = globals()[‘SGO’].values
dictio_scaled_values[‘SGO’] = scale_data(‘SGO’, data_array[‘SGO’])
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM , Bidirectional
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

def preparation_train(df_scaled,pas,train_len):

 train_data = df_scaled[0:int(train_len)]
 # Split the data into x_train and y_train data sets
 x_train = []
 y_train = []

 for i in range(window_size, len(train_data)):
    x_train.append(train_data[i-window_size:i, 0])
    y_train.append(train_data[i, 0])


# Convert the x_train and y_train to numpy arrays
 x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)

# Reshape the data
 x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))

 return x_train,y_train
def preparation_test(df_scaled,pas,train_len):

    # Create the data sets x_test and y_test
 df_test= df_scaled[train_len:, :]
 x_test = []
 y_test = []
 for i in range(pas, len(df_test)):
    x_test.append(df_test[i-pas:i, 0])
    y_test.append(df_test[i, 0])
 Convert the x_test and y_test to numpy arrays
 x_test, y_test = np.array(x_test), np.array(y_test)

 # Reshape the data
 x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1))

 return x_test,y_test
def create_model(pas):
 model = Sequential()
 model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=128, activation=‘relu’, input_shape=(pas, 
 1),return_sequences=True)))
 model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=64, activation=‘relu’,return_sequences=True)))
 model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=32, activation=‘relu’)))
 model.add(Dense(1))
 return model

epochs = 300
batch_size = 256
window_size=60
model = create_model(window_size)
model.compile(optimizer=‘adam’, loss=‘mean_squared_error’)
x_train,y_train = preparation_train(dictio_scaled_values[‘SGO’],window_size,dic_train_len[‘SGO’])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs,verbose=1)
fichier_modele = “SGO.h5”
model.save(fichier_modele)
from keras.models import load_model
def Backtesting_real(df,symbols,train_len,pas):

 Pred_Array_Global=df[int(train_len)-pas:int(train_len)]
 test=df[train_len:]
 # Get the models predicted price values
 fichier_modele = f"{symbols}.h5"
 model = load_model(fichier_modele)
 scaler2=dictio_scalers[symbols]
 Pred_Array_Global=scaler2.fit_transform(Pred_Array_Global)

 for i in range(0,len(test)):
    Pred_Array_Global=np.array(Pred_Array_Global)
    Pred_Array=Pred_Array_Global[i:i+pas]
    # Convert the data to a numpy array
    Pred_Array = np.array(Pred_Array)

    
    # Reshape the data
    Pred_Array_Input = np.reshape(Pred_Array,(1,pas, 1 ))
    predictions = model.predict(Pred_Array_Input,verbose=0)

    Pred_Array_Global=np.append(Pred_Array_Global,predictions)
    

 Pred_Array_Global=Pred_Array_Global.reshape(-1,1)
 #pdb.set_trace()
 Pred_Array_Global2 = scaler2.inverse_transform(Pred_Array_Global)
 Pred_Array_Global2=Pred_Array_Global2[pas:]
 rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean(((Pred_Array_Global2 - test) ** 2)))
 print("RMSE de l'action",symbols,":", rmse)
 test_data={}
 test_data['Predictions'] = Pred_Array_Global2
 test_data['Close']=test
 #pdb.set_trace()
 # Visualize the data
 plt.figure(figsize=(16,6))
 plt.title('Model')
 plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=18)
 plt.ylabel('Close Price USD ($)', fontsize=18)
 for k, v in test_data.items():
    plt.plot(range(1, len(v) + 1), v, '.-', label=k)
 plt.legend([ 'Predictions','Close'], loc='lower right')
 plt.savefig(f"Backtesting {symbols}.png")
Backtesting_real(data_array[‘SGO’],‘SGO’,dic_train_len[‘SGO’],60)
```

[image]

Comment: Be careful with `ReLU` activation and `LSTM` https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/446017. Not saying it's completely wrong, but it's not as widely accepted as with e.g. CNNs.

Comment: Also, you should not use `fit_transform` on the test data, just `transform` with a scaler that is fitted on the training data.